# Current Carrying Coil - Torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

i'm stuck on how to answer the last part of this question and would really appreciate some pointers.

> A rectangular coil (sides $a = 15 \, \mathrm{cm}$ and $b = 20 \, \mathrm{cm}$, $m= 15 \, \mathrm{g}$), is suspended by one
>   of its shorter sides, and lies in a vertical plane due to its weight. The coil carries a
>   current $I = 3 \, \mathrm{A}$, directed counterclockwise. If a uniform magnetic field $B = 0.06 \, \mathrm{T}$
>   directed upwards is switched on, the coil rotates around the $x$ axis until it reaches a
>   new equilibrium position (see figure). Determine:
>
> (a) the magnitude of the magnetic moment of the coil;
>
> (b) the torque acting on the coil when the coil is in a vertical position;
>
> (c) the angle  that the coil forms with the vertical axis when the coil reaches the
>   equilibrium position.

a) $\mu = NIA$ (The question makes no mention of the number of coils, so I assume 1)

$= 0.09 \, \mathrm{Am^{2}}$

b) $\tau = NIA(B \sin \theta)$

$\theta = 90\deg$

$\tau = NIAB = 5.4 \cdot 10^{-3} \, \mathrm{Nm}$

And now I'm stuck... I can picture in my head what I need to do, but I can't figure out how to apply it. I have worked out a "turning" force on the coil and I know it's length and mass, but I am unsure of how to use this info to find $\theta$.

How do I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Please put units into `\mathrm{...}` as they should not be italic. Stuff like “MagneticMoment” needs to be in `\text{...}`. Even better, use `\mu` for the magnetic moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the torque of the coil when it has the angle $\theta$, namely $\tau = NIAB \sin(\theta)$. The equilibrium will be reached when the total torque on the coil will be zero.

So look at the torque by gravity: It will pull at the center of mass, which lies $b/2$ away from the axis. Its mass is $m = 0.015 \, \mathrm{kg}$. That will give you around $F = mg = 0.15 \, \mathrm N$ of pull vertically down. The length of the lever is $b/2$, and you will have to take the angle between lever and pull into account, which is $\pi/2-\theta$. So the torque by gravity will be:
$$ \tau_\text G = \frac b2 mg \sin(\pi/2-\theta)$$

Which is
$$ \tau_\text G = \frac b2 mg \cos(\theta)$$

So you need to find $\theta$ so that $\tau = \tau_\text G$. I hope this is correct and I did not make any sign mistakes.